# Existence and Uniqueness of non-Lipschitz function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does the differential equation
\begin{align*}
\dot{x}=x^2 sin(1/x^2)
\end{align*}
with initial condition $x(0)=0$ have a unique solution? Since the function $x^2 sin(1/x^2)$ is not locally Lipschitz at the origin, the classical existence and uniqueness theorem does not apply.

Comment: Have you tried to solve the ODE?

Comment: Yes. However, I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Hint: the constant solutions exist every $x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k\pi}}$ for $k\in\Bbb{Z}^+$ and uniqueness is guaranteed for all of them.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the argument here. The IVP $\dot{x}=x^{2/3}$, $x(0)=0$ also has unique solutions for points arbitrarily close to the origin yet it fails to have a unique solution.

Comment: @Todd your "counterexample" fails to have constant solutions other than $0$. Can you intersect any of these?